# Improve text classification accuracy by using POS tagging - NLP

Tags: python, nlp, text-classification, naivebayes, pos-tagger

I am doing a project which category a tweet into Health and politics categories. I used the Naive Bayes algorithm for classification.

I am trying to improve the accuracy of the Naive Bayes classification by applying POS tagging. Because I think, assign linguistic information will improve the classification efficiency.

My dataset consists like below after preprocessing and applying pos tagging:

```
ID      tweet                               Category   pos_tagged_tweet
1   හාමුදුරුවරු සියලූම පූජකයන්ගේ මානසික සෞඛ්යය  Health    [(හාමුදුරුවරු, NNC), (සියලූම, NNC), (පූජකයන්ගේ, NNC), (මානසික, JJ), (සෞඛ්යය, NNC), (., FS)]
2   ද්විපාර්ශවික එකඟතා ජන ජීවිත සෞඛ්යය මනාව    Politics  [(ද්විපාර්ශවික, NNP), (එකඟතා, NNP), (ජන, JJ), (ජීවිත, NNJ), (සෞඛ්යය, NNC), (මනාව, RB),  (., FS)]
3   කරැනාකර චින නිෂ්පාදිත එන්නත ලබාගත්         Health    [(කරැනාකර, NNC), (චින, VP), (නිෂ්පාදිත, VP), (එන්නත, NNC), (ලබාගත්, VP),(., FS)]
'
'
'
```

I need to know how to apply the **pos_tagged_tweet** column and **Category** column for the Naive Bayes algorithm to categorize whether a tweet is a Health based tweet or a political tweet. I am using python and NLTK for my implementations.

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to replace the words by their corresponding pos_tags in a sentence and form new attributes like below:

```
sentence = ["A quick brown fox jumped over the cat",
        "An apple fell from a tree",
        "I like old western classics"]
tokenized_sents = [nltk.word_tokenize(i) for i in sentence]
print(tokenized_sents)
pos_tags = [nltk.pos_tag(token) for token in tokenized_sents]

print(pos_tags)

[[('A', 'DT'), ('quick', 'JJ'), ('brown', 'NN'), ('fox', 'NN'), ('jumped', 'VBD'), ('over', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('cat', 'NN')], [('An', 'DT'), ('apple', 'NN'), ('fell', 'VBD'), ('from', 'IN'), ('a', 'DT'), ('tree', 'NN')], [('I', 'PRP'), ('like', 'VBP'), ('old', 'JJ'), ('western', 'JJ'), ('classics', 'NNS')]]
```

Now create word vectors from pos_tags by replacing the words in the sentences by the pos_tags.

```
# from gensim.test.utils import common_texts
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

 pos_tag_list = [['DT', 'JJ', 'NN', 'NN', 'VBD', 'IN', 'DT', 'NN'],
                      ['DT','NN','VBD','IN','DT','NN'],['PRP','VBP','JJ','JJ','NNS']]
 w2v_model = Word2Vec(min_count=1,
                 window=2,
                 size=30,
                 sample=1e-5, 
                 alpha=0.01, 
                 min_alpha=0.0007, 
                 negative=0,
                 workers=2)
w2v_model.build_vocab(pos_tag_list, progress_per=1)
w2v_model.train(pos_tag_list, total_examples=w2v_model.corpus_count, epochs=3, report_delay=1)

# get the vectors for the Pos_tags from w2v_model
 my_dict = dict({})
 for index, key in enumerate(w2v_model.wv.vocab):
    my_dict[key] = w2v_model.wv[key]

 # Sample Output vector for pos_tags, we got 30-dimensional word vector since
 we used size=30.

  {'DT': array([-0.01487986,  0.00341667,  0.00576919, -0.01203213,  0.01111736,
     0.01643543,  0.00583243,  0.00283635, -0.00892249,  0.01334178,
     0.01324782,  0.00843606,  0.00965199,  0.00849338, -0.00584444,
    -0.00482766,  0.01218408, -0.00959254, -0.00172328,  0.01302824,
    -0.00374165, -0.01516393, -0.00604865,  0.00170989,  0.00843781,
    -0.01403714,  0.00150807,  0.01511062,  0.00798908,  0.0088043 ],
   dtype=float32)}
```

Now for every entry in pos_tag_list replace the pos_tags with vectors and create a training dataset for the Naive bayes model. You can also use actual word vectors along with pos_tags and create a comprehensive dataset. I didn't specifically work on it but depending on the research what I found I think this might work. Give it a try and check.

Comment: Thank you soo much @Priya. I will give a try.

Answer (score 0):

First, when asking a question please follow the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and include a minimal reproducible example, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Now, I'm assuming you're using nltk and everything is in English. First, you need to tokenize your sentences, and then apply the POS Tagging:

```
import nltk
 
sentence = "Can you help me with this?"
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
pos = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)

print(pos)
```

And that will give you the following list:

```
[('Can', 'MD'), ('you', 'PRP'), ('help', 'VB'), ('me', 'PRP'), ('with', 'IN'), ('this', 'DT'), ('?', '.')]
```

You can find more information about NLTK on their [documentation](http://www.nltk.org/index.html).

Comment: One idea is to replace the words by their corresponding postags